# jquery data not inputting to postgresql database (django)

Tags: django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I have a [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) in my base.html. The UI calendar appears in the page, so I know the libraries, etc. are set up ok, but when I submit, the date is not added into the database. Other data on the form is input.

I don't believe it's a formatting issue either, since I added a new CharField column and still get no results.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from widgets import *
import datetime
from django.forms import widgets


class DateTestSaveForm(forms.Form):
    date_nm = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Date Name',
        max_length=30
    )
    fromdate = forms.DateField(label=u'date of birth', input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', '%m/%d/%Y',], required=False, widget=widgets.DateInput(attrs={
        'class': 'required'
    }))
    testdate = forms.CharField(label=u'test')
```

base.html

```
  <script type="text/javascript">



    $(function() {
      // $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' });
    $( "#id_fromdate" ).datepicker();
    });


    $(function() {
      // $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' });
    $( "#id_testdate" ).datepicker();
    });


</script>
```

views.py

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from d2.tt.models import *
from django import forms
from d2.tt.forms import *
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext


def datetest_save_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = DateTestSaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            date_nm, dummy = DateTest.objects.get_or_create(
                date_nm=form.cleaned_data['date_nm']
            )
            fromdate = form.cleaned_data['fromdate']
            testdate = form.cleaned_data['testdate']
            return HttpResponseRedirect('main_page.html') 
    else:
        form = DateTestSaveForm()
    return render_to_response('datetest_save.html', {
        'form': form, 
    },RequestContext(request))




def main_page(request):
    return render_to_response(
    'main_page.html',RequestContext(request)
    )
```

datetest_save.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}DateTest Title{% endblock %}
{% block head %}DateTest Head{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" value="save it" /> 
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Changed forms.DateField to forms.CharField in TestDate
EDIT: Added views.py, added datetest.html

Comment: Are you aware that between "jquery" and "postgresql" there are some layers that you completely ignored in your question? This shows that you did not try to determine, whether the issue is with  JavaScript code, connectivity/AJAX call, validation or database structure. In other words: what have you tried?

Comment: Since the jquery calendar object is present when I click in the form, I am assuming that the jquery is set up correctly. I also created the additional (NOT NULL) CharField column which would allow a much wider range of data to be added, regardless of format, to be entered. So, of the items above, I **think** the only thing not tested is AJAX. If my assumptions / testing methods are lacking, your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is the data submitted to your view ? Use your browsers inspector tool to verify that.
May we see your view ? Did you debug your view ? Does the request.POST param contains the entered date value ?

Comment: Yes, data (date_nm) submits and saves to the db. Both the DateField and CharField columns submitted by jquery are null. I will look at the browser tool to see what data is being submitted.

Comment: @jabs: This is exactly what I meant: check if the data is retrieved from DOM, sent, received by the server, passed to the model field and saved. Some part of this process is failing and **you** need to identify which. We cannot do it for you, we can only try to help you when you hit some specific problem (eg. "The data is sent to the server, but server does not see it").

Comment: Btw. You showed us only datepicker initialization script, nothing more on the page itself. Plus, you incorrectly use jQuery domready support: $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); is exactly the same as $(function(){ ... }); - read jQuery's docs. You use attach handler within handler (this is probably not causing issues, but is redundant).

Comment: @Tadeck - thanks for the function tip - corrected. 

Looks like it's at least creating the value. I changed the submit button to a jquery submit() function and trapped it, then called it in the form. After trapping it, the "Watch Expressions" console (Chrome tools) has values:

    id_fromdate.value: "08/01/2012"
    id_testdate.value: "08/02/2012"

Comment: I added the html page that calls the form. I didn't add anything more to base.html, where the jquery datepicker lives. Since the calendar pop-up window is present, assuming that everything is ok there. Of course, I'll add that whole file if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Missing the save method.